# semantic map input

Tags: navigation, mapping, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im new in knowrob package and would like to know what is the input and output of the semantic map. Is the bitmap image a input and semantic map can be create from bitmap image or what is the general input ( like RGB image or point claud datas) for semantic maps in knowrob. Please any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41822/semantic-map-input/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A semantic map is a data structure, it is not a processing unit, so there are no inputs or outputs. The map consists of object instances at different poses in space and their composition of sub-parts. The objects are described as instances of more generic object classes and inherit their properties. I've already pointed you to related publications and can only recommend to read about the concepts behind semantic maps, e.g. in [1].

You can, in principle, create semantic maps from very different input sources: In [1], RGB-D data is used, in the KnowRob tutorial at the ROS Fall School 2010, we have interfaced the [tabletop_object_detector](http://ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_detector), you can use image-based recognition methods like the [RoboEarth object recognition system](http://ros.org/wiki/roboearth), or you can build the map yourself, manually or with the (experimental) [semantic map editor](http://ros.org/wiki/mod_semantic_map) [(some docs)](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Mod_semantic_map).

Moritz

[1] http://ias.cs.tum.edu/_media/spezial/bib/iros12semantic_mapping.pdf

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-19**:
Ok. Thanks. So none of this methods is based on simple bitmap (black and white ) png image???

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-08-19**:
No. If you want to automatically create a 3D map with objects inside, you need to have an input format that provides this information. Black and white PNG images are great for distinguishing obstacles from free space, but don't tell you which objects are where. How should the system know?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-19**:
ok. Understand. Thanks.